# Transforming/Mapping models

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns, automapper

I have a generic model which is used to store all the data using an ORM technology. This model has to be occasionally transformed into another model to ‘do something’. At the moment I am using this (simplified)  approach where the generic model stores weight in kilogram and the target model stores it in pounds:

```
public class GenericModelClassA
{
    public virtual double Weight { get; set; } 
}

public interface IModelX
{
    double Weight { get; set; }
}

public class ModelXClassA : GenericModelClassA, IModelX
{
    private const double WeightConversionFactor = 2.20462;

    public override double Weight
    {
        set
        {
        base.Weight = value / WeightConversionFactor;
        }
        get
        {
        return base.Weight * WeightConversionFactor;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a decent approach to the problem? I have heard about model driven transformation (MDT) languages to query/view/transform/operational (QVTO). Is my approach too naive? Would you recommend MDT languages? Any feedback/opinions would be very much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Christian

Comment: Not sure if you read everything or if I was not clear enough ...

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use inheritance here, but instead have the base model as a private property.  If only because it means code that consumes ModelXClassA doesn't need to be aware of GenericModelClassA.

Comment: well, I could be stupid, but I have no idea what you are attempting to ask....

Comment: Good point. So aggregation rather than inheritance to hide properties of the GenericModel from the consumer of ModelX?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat I am asking about good approaches for model transformation/mapping which should be a common problem. I apologize if I did not express myself clearly enough.

Comment: are you talking about a facade? I think you want the strategy pattern

Comment: I am aware of the facade and strategy pattern but do not believe they are appropriate here. A facade would map/use two or more complicated interface to a more simple generic interface. Strategies can be used to swap algorithms (e.g. for sorting) at run time. So not sure how these DPs apply to my situation but please furnish an answer to enlighten me.

Comment: I don't know what other cases you might have, and how frequent they'll be, but for the example you exposed you could have a `IWeight` interface  that has a `ToKilos()` or `ToPounds()` etc to do the transformation when being consumed, if you want to persist stuff in different weight systems, you might have a `IWeightSystem` object that does the conversion from your double value (as I think Mitch is suggesting), or a combination of both .. What other examples you have in mind in your transformations? and how often will they occur?

Comment: Another transformation may involve several fields of the generic model, which are mapped to one field of model X. The mapping would be performed by the getter method.

Comment: Can you give a real-life example on that? Why not keep the transformation in a different class?

Comment: Good point about keeping the transformation in a different class. I guess may main motivation of extending/aggregating the generic model is code reuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the OO point of view there are some concepts that are not explicitly model that may help in this situation. In this case you are representing and absolute amount and its unit of measure with a number (to which you can't delegate any responsibility, since it is not an object) and absorbing that conversion responsibility in your model object. In my opinion you should create a richer model that represents the situation:

- Class WeightUnit, with subclasses Kilo and Pound.
- Class Weight, that has an absolute number and a weight unit. In other words, a "weight" is a value plus the unit of weight that gives meaning to that value.
- Your model class has a weight variable.

I'm not familiar with C# so please bear with me here:

```
abstract public class WeightUnit
{
    abstract public function convertValueToKilo(float value);
    abstract public function convertValueToPounds(float value);
}

public class Kilo extends WeightUnit
{
    public function convertValueToKilo(float value) {return value;}
    public function convertValueToPounds(float value) {return value * 2.20462262;}
}

public class Pounds extends WeightUnit
{
    public function convertValueToKilo(float value) {return value / 2.20462262;}
    public function convertValueToPounds(float value) {return value;}
}

public class Weight
{
    protected WeightUnit unit;
    protected float value;

    public function Weight(float value, WeightUnit unit)
    {
      //set the internal state
    }

    public function toKilo()
    {
       return new Weight(this.unit.convertValueToKilo(this.value), new Kilo());
    }

    public function toPounds()
    {
       return new Weight(this.unit.convertValueToPounds(this.value), new Pounds());
    }
}
```

One of the issues with this implementation is that the amount of conversions explodes as more weigh unit you have. For those cases you generally select a "default" unit (e.g. Kilo) and all the other units know how to convert to/from kilo. In that case adding a new unit means adding one class and two methods. However some round errors may arise from doing this double conversion.

HTH

Comment: I like the fact that you inject the 'transformer' into Weight.

Comment: Thanks. I see this as a problem of responsibility assignment: who should know how to convert to/from another unit? The unit itself. There are measurement frameworks out there (I don't know in particular one for C#) that model things like weight units, distance units, time units, etc and the conversions between them.

Comment: Is there any reason for using an abstract class rather than an interface for WeightUnit? Would it not be better to define one transformer interface like WeightUnit and just implement one concrete transformer class which can be injected into Weight. I personally find it a bit overkill. Some of my classes have up to 50 properties (i.e. weights).

Comment: Sure, if the only thing that WeightUnit is going to do is to define a set of abstract methods (like in the example), it would be better modeled as an interface. I don't know your entire problem domain, so I can't tell the exact WeightUnit responsibilities. Maybe there is some behavior that can be abstracted in a class, I don't know.

Comment: Regarding the second observation (being it an overkill) I have to disagree. OOP is about having rich models and delegating the behavior to those objects. Why make it more complicate if it can be simple? Some people wuold say that having 100 objects instead of 50 floats is a problem or is slow. Well, that is what OOP languages are optimized for. I have made systems that had thousands of objects, and I don't think that that's an overkill; on the contrary, they were quite expressive (and flexible) models.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd do it.

**Domain**

```
public class Weight
{
   public Weight(decimal miligrams) { InMiligrams= miligrams;}

   public decimal InMiligrams {get;private set;}

   public decimal InGrams { get { return InMiligrams*1000; }}

   /* other conversions as properties */
}
```

**Persistence**

```
 public class StorageModel
 {
     public virtual decimal Weight {get;set;}
 }
```

**Mapping**

***Domain -> Persistence***

```
storage.Weight = weight.InMiligrams;
```

***Persistence -> Domain***

```
weight = new Weight(storage.Weight);
```

The Persistence layer and the Domain layer know that internally all weights are expressed in miligrams (or whatever other unit of measure you want).

Comment: I am sorry but I think you still misunderstand the problem. I have a generic model which is already persisted. This model has to be transformed into different models. I guess it is a bit like transforming the domain model into different view models. This actually reminds me of automapper ...